# DJANGO Error: UnboundLocalError at local variable 'cart_obj' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I have limited experience in coding, but I like django and python and I am trying to learn by completing a udemy course called "*Build a DJANGO ecommerce web application*.  It appears the course has some issues, but I have already invested several hours and want to get to the end!  Please help !!!

I am having problems with the cart build.  When I navigate to localhost/cart/cart I receive the above error.  I have not posted the settings.py as I think thhe error is limited to the views and models configuration. The relevant information is below:

**traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /cart/cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\pharmamart\cart\views.py", line 14, in cart_home
    cart_obj, new_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\pharmamart\cart\models.py", line 22, in new_or_get
    return cart_obj, new_obj
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cart_obj' referenced before assignment
[28/Mar/2021 10:38:40] "GET /cart/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72446
```

**cart/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from store.models import product, customer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save, m2m_changed

# Create your models here.
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", default= None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id =cart_id)
        if qs.count()==1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj-save()
            else:
                cart_obj = cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
                new_obj = True
                request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user = None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user is authenticated():
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('store.product')
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default = 0.0, max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    total = models.DecimalField(default = 0.0, max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args,**kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action =='post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        products = instance.product.all()
        total = 0
        for x in products:
            total += x.price
        if instance.subtotal != total:
            instance.subtotal = total
            instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=cart.product.through)

def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.total = instance.subtotal
pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender = cart)
```

**cart/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import cart, CartManager
from store.models import product

# Create your views here.
#def cart_create(user=None):
#   cart_obj = cart.objects.create(user = None)
#   print('New Cart created')
#   return cart_obj

def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    product = cart_obj.product.all()
    price = 0
    for x in products:
        total = x.price
    print (total) 
    cart_obj.total = total
    cart_obj.save()
    return render(request, "home.html", {})

def cart_update(request):
    product_id =1
    product_obj =product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    cart_obj, new_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    if product_obj in cart_obj.product.all():
        cart_obj.product.remove(product_obj)
    else:
        cart_obj.product.add(product_obj)
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Comment: In `new_or_get()`, the `cart_obj` variable is created only when `if qs.count()==1` is true.

Comment: This is the suggested code.  What would you advise if the better solution? @JohnGordon

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an else-block to your if-statement?

**cart/models.py**

```
if qs.count()==1:
    ...
else:
    cart_obj = # something
    new_obj = # something
return cart_obj, new_obj
```

Comment: Thankyou I did not try that.  I decided to terminate the tutorial as it was simply to outdated.  I commenced with a diffierent tutorial .  Thankyou for your suggestion and assistance